# How to identify the column name of a data table

Tags: c#, database

I have got a datatable with records from two different database tables. Each of the database tables have a column with the same name(eg: ID). The datatable generated will display the field ID of the two tables as ID and ID1. I need to sort the datatable with the ID of the second table. How can I identify which column of the datatable is the ID of the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the name of the columns in the SQL query

```
SELECT 
  FT.ID FIRSTTABLE_ID,
  ST.ID SECONDTABLE_ID
FROM FIRSTTABLE FT, SECONDTABLE ST
WHERE FT.ID = ST.FS_ID
```